# Setting up Postfix and Google G Suite email with WordPress

Tags: email, postfix, php-fpm, wordpress, apache2

I have finally got WordPress setup and working on my VPS using WP-CLI. It wasn't until I wanted to change my `Administration Email Address` found under `Settings > General` and submit forms from ContactForm7 when I realised I wasn't receiving any emails at the entered email addresses.

I have public domain I purchased with Namescheap and I have an email with Google G Suite (now Google Workspace). I will refer to my public domain as example.com throughout this post. My Linux server has the FQDN of `ubuntu-server.example.com` and my email is `info@example.com` with an alias email; `webmaster@example.com`.

I have Apache 2.4 installed and have opted to use the FPM version of PHP over `mod_php` as it's faster but at a cost of more memory. PHP and Apache run under the Linux user and group `www-data`.

I want to install Postfix so after following various guides I have setup 'Less Secure apps' on Gmail within the Google G Suite as I have 2FA enabled.

My unmodified `PHP.ini` file with the sendmail_path commented

**/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini**

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;mail.log = syslog
```

I'm having problems with my configuration and I've been using the log at `/var/log/mail.log` to diagnose the problems. I found a really useful article [here](https://www.mybluelinux.com/postfix-how-log-email-headers-like-from-to-and-subject/) showing how you can log the email headers.

**/etc/postfix/header_checks**

```
/^subject:/      WARN
/^to:/           WARN
/^from:/         WARN
/^Subject:/      WARN
/^To:/           WARN
/^From:/         WARN
```

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = ubuntu-server.example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, example.com, ubuntu-server.example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost
relayhost = [smtp-relay.gmail.com]:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

**/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd**

```
[smtp-relay.gmail.com]:587 webmaster@example.com:password
```

Simply changing the `Administration Email Address` in the WordPress' dashboard produces the following log:

**/var/log/mail.log (Changing Administration Email Address)**

```
Oct 14 20:34:50 ubuntu-server postfix/pickup[122612]: 615314047B: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Oct 14 20:34:50 ubuntu-server postfix/cleanup[122616]: 615314047B: warning: header To: personal-email@yahoo.co.uk from local; from=<www-data@example.com>
Oct 14 20:34:50 ubuntu-server postfix/cleanup[122616]: 615314047B: warning: header Subject: [The Surge Network] New Admin Email Address from local; from=<www-data@example.com>
Oct 14 20:34:50 ubuntu-server postfix/cleanup[122616]: 615314047B: warning: header From: WordPress <wordpress@example.com> from local; from=<www-data@example.com>
Oct 14 20:34:50 ubuntu-server postfix/cleanup[122616]: 615314047B: message-id=<kMHoPRoBbCcWwZBqBPaFwW9iLVNFC9VoF2jSlCUP7Y@example.com>
Oct 14 20:34:50 ubuntu-server postfix/qmgr[122614]: 615314047B: from=<www-data@example.com>, size=1000, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 14 20:34:50 ubuntu-server postfix/smtp[122618]: 615314047B: SASL authentication failed; server smtp-relay.gmail.com[74.125.133.28] said: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at?535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials i127sm10296wmi.19 - gsmtp
Oct 14 20:34:50 ubuntu-server postfix/smtp[122618]: connect to smtp-relay.gmail.com[2a00:1450:400c:c08::1c]:587: Network is unreachable
Oct 14 20:34:50 ubuntu-server postfix/smtp[122618]: 615314047B: to=<personal-email@yahoo.co.uk>, relay=none, delay=0.09, delays=0.01/0/0.08/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to smtp-relay.gmail.com[2a00:1450:400c:c08::1c]:587: Network is unreachable)
```

As I stated earlier Apache and PHP run under the `www-data` Linux user and group (their default's) and these appear the log quite significantly. The interesting thing is if I submit a form through ContactForm7 `www-data` seems to overrule again.

[image: ContactForm7 Mail Settings]

**/var/log/mail.log (Submitting CF7 Form)**

```
Oct 14 21:09:04 ubuntu-server postfix/pickup[122612]: C31844047F: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Oct 14 21:09:04 ubuntu-server postfix/cleanup[123010]: C31844047F: warning: header To: personal-email@yahoo.co.uk from local; from=<www-data@example.com>
Oct 14 21:09:04 ubuntu-server postfix/cleanup[123010]: C31844047F: warning: header Subject: =?us-ascii?Q?John_Smith_has_sumbitted_a_form_at_WordPress_Si?=  =?us-ascii?Q?te?= from local; from=<www-data@example.com>
Oct 14 21:09:04 ubuntu-server postfix/cleanup[123010]: C31844047F: warning: header From: Webmaster <webmaster@example.com> from local; from=<www-data@example.com>
Oct 14 21:09:04 ubuntu-server postfix/cleanup[123010]: C31844047F: message-id=<uJzVxnCArv7DHvzHsYwBz6hbm6um3CZb5qcLzXTXBfc@example.com>
Oct 14 21:09:04 ubuntu-server postfix/qmgr[122614]: C31844047F: from=<www-data@example.com>, size=693, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 14 21:09:04 ubuntu-server postfix/smtp[123012]: C31844047F: SASL authentication failed; server smtp-relay.gmail.com[74.125.140.28] said: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at?535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials b14sm13955wrm.42 - gsmtp
Oct 14 21:09:04 ubuntu-server postfix/smtp[123012]: connect to smtp-relay.gmail.com[2a00:1450:400c:c08::1c]:587: Network is unreachable
Oct 14 21:09:04 ubuntu-server postfix/smtp[123012]: C31844047F: to=<personal-email@yahoo.co.uk>, relay=none, delay=0.14, delays=0.03/0.03/0.08/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to smtp-relay.gmail.com[2a00:1450:400c:c08::1c]:587: Network is unreachable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not set your system hostname to your naked domain name. Do not set Postfix's mailname to the naked domain name. Do not add the naked domain name to Postfix's mydestination, or to any other Postfix configuration option. Doing any of these will cause Postfix to try to deliver the mail locally rather than sending it out to the Internet.

Name the system with a subdomain of your domain name. Give the fully qualified domain name, including subdomain, as the Postfix mailname. For example you might call your system `capacitor` and the FQDN would be `capacitor.example.com`. Mail for example.com would then be delivered wherever it is supposed to go. And only mail for someone @ capacitor.example.com would be delivered locally (unless you forward it somewhere, of course).

Comment: I've updated my post, re-wording everything and providing better info. I've also started over with my Postfix configuration by purging the application from Linux, re-installing it and starting over to ensure there wasn't something wrong that I've done. I have also given my server a hostname name that prefixes my public domain as you were pointing out.

Comment: @willowen100 There's not much we can do about Google not accepting your password.

Comment: Google G Suite only accepts `info` and `webmaster` @example.com That's why it is coming back with authentication errors.